# Make flutter application fullscreen | How to enable fullscreen in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fullscreen

How can I make a flutter application fullscreen. I already found out how to hide the status bar [Hide Android Status Bar On Flutter App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877288/hide-android-status-bar-on-flutter-app). but I can't seem to find how to hide the android navigation bar.

Comment: @FarshidABZ The link you provided is for the Android SDK - Bobola was clearly looking for a Flutter solution.

Comment: The most up-to-date solution is to use [`setEnabledSystemUiMode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69326491/6618622)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

It's exactly like for Android status bar.

Doing `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` hides both the status bar and the navigation bar.

p/s : use this
`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);` to disable full screen mode.

Comment: I am having a problem. I want this behaviour on only one screen. In initState `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` does the job to hide status bar and navigation bar, but in onDispose `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values)` doesn't bring them back.

Comment: Just for clarification: the `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` has to be added inside the build method of the class, but before the 'return'.

Comment: @GurleenSethi have you tried this: `SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays()`?

Comment: This does not work!  When a text field got focus, the virtual keyboard appears, together with the mobile phone status bar, after the user enter something into the text field and lost focus, the status bar is still there, which means that the app is now not in full screen.  It is said in the documentation that after the text field lost focus, we can only call the SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays again AFTER 1 SECOND, but I've tens of Text Fields in my app, how should I make my app always in Full Screen Mode?

Comment: For someone who doesn't know, you have to import 'Service.dart' `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
`

Comment: @GurleenSethi `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.bottom, SystemUiOverlay.top]);` works for me

Comment: The top bar is still there but without text. Why?

Comment: for some reason it leaves a black blank space where the status bar was ( when I try to do a full screen,)

Comment: This is now deprecated! Can someone tell me the alternatives?

Comment: @Balaji Check out SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive); Not very sure about which mode we need to use though

Comment: `setEnabledSystemUIOverlays` is now deprecated and replaced by `setEnabledSystemUIMode`

Comment: Can you help me with webview. I am playing video in webview and i want the video player in webview to enter full screen without pressing the button on video player.

Answer (score 65):

#### Use `setEnabledSystemUIMode` (Recommended):

- **Fullscreen (with restoration):**

  ```dart
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
  ```
- **Fullscreen (without restoration):**

  ```dart
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
  ```
- **Showing a particular overlay:**

  ```dart
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
    SystemUiMode.manual,
    overlays: [
      SystemUiOverlay.top, // Shows Status bar and hides Navigation bar
    ],
  );
  ```
- **Exit fullscreen:**

  ```dart
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
  ```

<sub>Restoration: Once the status and navigation bar are presented, they will be hidden again.</sub>

Comment: `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);` is not for Exiting full screen. From doc: `The system overlays will not disappear or reappear in this mode as they are permanently displayed on top of the application.`

Comment: This answer should be used to update the accepted one: we should use `setEnabledSystemUIMode` over `setEnabledSystemUIOverlays`, since the latter is now deprecated.

Comment: @venir Or you could say *This should be the accepted answer* now ;)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad yes, totally, my bad.

Comment: SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge); does unfortunatelly not fully restore. some elements are then hidden behind the bottom navbar. For me this did the trick exiting full screen:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
                    SystemUiMode.manual,
                    overlays: [
                      SystemUiOverlay.top,
                      SystemUiOverlay.bottom,
                    ],
                  );

Answer (score 54):

```
// to hide only bottom bar:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.top]);

// to hide only status bar: 
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

// to hide both:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([]);
```

Comment: You are making a mistake.

Comment: @JideGuru - Yes, that is correct...there is a slight error in the code. I suggested the correct code in the edit I submitted. Hopefully the correction will be approved by the peer reviewers.

Comment: Can I again enable statusBar and Navigation Bar ?
If yes, then what is the procedure?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you use: SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
and swipe down the top bar - it shows up and stays permanently...

Answer (score 14):

Finally i found a way to set in one class for fullscreen. and disable on other classes.

To set full screen put this code in **initState()**

> SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

and to set back to normal. In **dispose()**

> SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);

in the same class.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    super.dispose();
  }
    
  @override
  initState() {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    super.initState();
  }
```

you can't set the

```
SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();
```

in **dispose()**. because its already saying

```
**Restores the system overlays to the last settings provided via [setEnabledSystemUIOverlays].**
May be used when the platform force enables/disables UI elements.
          
For example, when the Android keyboard disables hidden status and navigation bars,
this can be called to re-disable the bars when the keyboard is closed.
          
On Android, the system UI cannot be changed until 1 second after the previous
change. This is to prevent malware from permanently hiding navigation buttons.`
```

Answer (score 9):

Below code is working perfect for fullscreen

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
```

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; 
////

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
///Set color status bar
 SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
   return Scaffold(
   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
   body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          'images/ic_splash_logo.png',
          width: 97.0,
          height: 115.0,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        Text(
          'iComplain',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24,
              color: Color(0xFF174D73),
            fontFamily: 'Helvetica'
          ),
        ),
      ],
     ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

This hides the top and bottom bars but the app size remains the same. It does not expand to full screen height.

Comment: Hi, have someone find any way to use full height, when top bar is hidden?

Answer (score 7):

**Update**:

To Enable full screen in flutter app in your stateless or stateful widget

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
```

To exit the full screen mode

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values);
```

Example

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // Start full screen
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // Exit full screen
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

this is my experience if i add `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` in `init` or `dispose` , status bar and navigation bar will back when you use keyboard , but if you use it like this it work perfect:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // To make this screen full screen.
    // It will hide status bar and notch.
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

    // full screen image for splash screen.
    return Container(
            child: new Image.asset('assets/splash.png', fit: BoxFit.fill));
      }
    }
```

inside of your widget

Answer (score 3):

Use `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` in your main, you can use  `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` beforehand if you get errors.

But, this does not persist through the app, and after a textfield loses focus you're supposed to call `SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays()`  after 1 second. Apparently ["This is to prevent malware from permanently hiding navigation buttons"](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/restoreSystemUIOverlays.html). (Why not just keep the swipe down gesture to prevent being 'stuck inside' the app? )
in any case
My app is full of forms and that method seems like a lot of work.

I guess this solution is a bit hacky but i just created a service running in the background on a timer every second running `SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays()` it looks like this:

```
    class FullscreenService{
  
    Timer? timer;
    static FullscreenService? _instance;
    FullscreenService._internal() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(
    Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => 
    SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays);
    }

    factory FullscreenService() => _instance ?? FullscreenService._internal();

    void cancelTimer(){
    timer!.cancel();
   }
  }
```

I'm hoping i wont have to use this in the future and if anyone has any ideas how to avoid this while still maintaining fullscreen please let me know... but at least its working for now.

Comment: In case you want your app to always be in the immersive mode, you can just use `SystemUiMode.immersiveStick`. This will automatically reset any overlays after a certain delay. This however does not work for manual mode when you just want to hide status bar e.g.

Comment: btw, it must be: `Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays())}`. Brackets were missing

Comment: and even better: you can use `SystemChrome.setSystemUIChangeCallback()` to listen to system ui mode changes. Then you don't need a permanently running timer

Answer (score 2):

In new version Flutter use this code:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
```

or

```
 SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [this pub package](https://pub.dev/packages/fullscreen) to do in a clean way.

If you want to enable it for specific screen, make sure this screen is a StatefulWidget (you can easily convert it with your IDE tools) and override the initState() and dispose():

```
import 'package:fullscreen/fullscreen.dart';

class ClockScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClockScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ClockScreen> createState() => _ClockScreenState();
}

class _ClockScreenState extends State<ClockScreen> {

  @override
  void initState(){
    FullScreen.enterFullScreen(FullScreenMode.EMERSIVE_STICKY);
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose(){
    FullScreen.exitFullScreen();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]); in your initState() like this:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Splash");

    // Start full screen
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  }
```

to start the screen in full-screen mode.

Next use SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values); in your dispose() function to exit full-screen mode for next screens.

```
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // Exit full screen
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

using `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` in `initState()` or `build()` method calling `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` which is rebuilding the widget and calling the `build()` method twice, to resolve this issue,  I am using this function into my `main()` function

```
void main() {

SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
...
...
..
.
```

Answer (score -21):

The AppBar is your Navigation bar so just remove it from your Code as illustrate below

//New This Code it should work , the AppBar is navigation bar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {      
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new MaterialApp(
         home: new Scaffold(
           body: new Center(
              child: new Text('Hello World'),
           ),
         ),
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add some description why your code works and make sure to correctly format your code next time. It isn't readable otherwise.

Comment: Please define your answer