# What is the best way to make fullscreen for flutter video_player?

Tags: flutter, video-player

Im trying to implement video_player in my Flutter project and need your tips)
So, requirements are: player have to work inline and fullscreen and it must have custom controls.

I've tried to use video_player itself. And there were no problems till I`ve started implementation of fullscreen mode. I did it with help of another special screen for "fullscreen" mode. And had to path current video progress and status (play/pause) there.

Is there any better way to do this without creating new screen and new instance of player for fullscreen?

Chewie? Yes, I've tried it as well. Much better experience of fullscreen. But I've also bumped into some issues. First of all it rotate video into landscape mode in fullscreen. This answer https://github.com/brianegan/chewie/issues/137 helps, but there is still some visible rotation to landscape and then back. not the best experience, i think.
And controls... If you put custom controls outside of Chewie - there are not rendering in fullscreen. If you put them in 'overlay" property - they become static and I don't see the way to update there values (change Icon and set Progress value). Any example of usage "customControls" property?

Has anyone same isuues? Any examples demos or tips? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640116/make-flutter-application-fullscreen?rq=1 This should help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make flutter application fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640116/make-flutter-application-fullscreen)

Comment: @gorevanova Isn't it about showing/hiding device system bars?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Chewie 
"customControls" are not shown if you set "showControls" to `false`

A bit confusing as for me

But their update during runtime is still a mystery

**UPDATE 2**

To make Chewie customControls work with progressbar and play/pause properly you chould path in your controls widget controller and listen for its changes from there