# How can I make a flutter app full screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

I have tried different things from different sites and articles but i cannot get rid the black bar on top

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 1):

it's been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640116/make-flutter-application-fullscreen)

tl;dr
add this piece code to the main function, before runApp()

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])
```

code:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(<SystemUiOverlay>[]);

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

the screen you want to make will be like this

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

result:
[image: image result]

without `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])`:
[image]

Comment: I still get the black bar on top

Comment: if you want to have really full screen, then you need to remove SafeArea before Scaffold

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: let me edit my answer

Comment: I cannot make it work can you please help me I'm a bit new to this

Comment: can i see your code?
by the way have you seen my edited code and result?

Comment: i have posted it as an answer check it out

Comment: i think you are using SafeArea or some other implementation of it somewhere above the screen scaffold.

Comment: i don't think so. edited the code tell me if you find anything

Comment: ```
        'introScreen': (context) => introScreen(),
        'homePage': (context) => MyHomePage()
```
check those codes, there must be something.. I've tried my code on my android and ios and there's no problem with that.. please re-check your code I guess

Comment: the only thing i have on my home page is ``` resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true, ```