# Full Screen Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How to enable and disable a full-screen mode in the check box. I think this is the use if and else statement. I will share my code.

```
 onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  thu = val!;
                  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
                    SystemUiMode.manual,
                    overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom],
                  );
                });
              }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `val`is a boolean, e.g. from a switch, you can use the following if-else statement to distinguish between the two cases.

```
 onChanged: (val) {
   setState(() {
     if (val) { // Fullscreen mode
       SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
         overlays: [],
       );
     } else { // Disable fullscreen mode
       SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
         overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values,
       );
     }
   });
 }),
```

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640116/make-flutter-application-fullscreen) for more information on the `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode` method.

Comment: The code is error i think there is something is missing on " if " please check

Comment: Do you have the precise error message?

Comment: I solved the Error, but I think there was some mistake when it worked on mobile; please check.

Comment: if (val) {
                        // Fullscreen mode
                        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
                          SystemUiMode.manual,
                          overlays: [
                            SystemUiOverlay.bottom,
                            //SystemUiOverlay.top
                          ],
                        );
                      }

Comment: else {
                        // Disable fullscreen mode
                        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
                          SystemUiMode.manual,
                          overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values,
                        );
                      }

Answer (score 0):

try this
// to hide only bottom bar:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

// to hide only status bar:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
```

// to hide both:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([]);
```