# full-screen content on flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a storis screen where there is an image in the background, I'm trying to make the image cover the entire screen including the status bar and use `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive)` for this, it works fine for Android, but on iOS it is displayed with white stripes on the sides

[image]
[image]

```
    class StoriesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String text;
  final String backgroundMedia;
  final String? promoCode;
  final MediaTypes mediaType;
  const StoriesPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.text,
    required this.backgroundMedia,
    this.promoCode,
    required this.mediaType,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StoriesPage> createState() => _StoriesPageState();
}

class _StoriesPageState extends State<StoriesPage> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
    if (widget.mediaType == MediaTypes.video) {
      _videoController =
          VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(widget.backgroundMedia))
            ..initialize().then((value) {
              _videoController.play();
              _videoController.setLooping(true);
              setState(() {});
            });
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.mediaType == MediaTypes.video ? _videoController.dispose() : null;
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      widget.mediaType == MediaTypes.image
          ? Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(widget.backgroundMedia),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
            )
          : _videoController.value.isInitialized
              ? SizedBox.expand(
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: _videoController.value.size.width,
                      height: _videoController.value.size.height,
                      child: VideoPlayer(_videoController),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: context.colors.primary,
                  ),
                ),
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                const Color.fromARGB(255, 6, 11, 17).withOpacity(0),
                const Color.fromARGB(60, 21, 44, 67).withOpacity(0.5),
                const Color.fromARGB(60, 10, 20, 31).withOpacity(1)
              ]),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              widget.title,
              style: context.text.headline1.copyWith(
                  height: 1.21,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 34),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text(
              widget.text,
              style: context.text.body3.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            widget.promoCode != null
                ? Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 32),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: const ButtonStyle(
                                backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                    Colors.transparent),
                                elevation: MaterialStatePropertyAll(0),
                                side: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await Clipboard.setData(
                                      ClipboardData(text: widget.promoCode!))
                                  .then((_) {
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                    const SnackBar(
                                        content: Text('Скопировано')));
                              });
                            },
                            child: Text(widget.promoCode.toString())),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
                                      text: widget.promoCode.toString()))
                                  .then((_) {
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                    const SnackBar(
                                        content: Text('Скопировано')));
                              });
                            },
                            child: const Text('Скопировать')),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : const SizedBox(),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: Container(
              height: 48,
              width: 48,
              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                  shape: CircleBorder(), color: Colors.white),
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  size: 24,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640116/make-flutter-application-fullscreen-how-to-enable-fullscreen-in-flutter

Comment: I already use this method in my code, but it only works for android

Comment: Have you checked it?  with SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky

Comment: yes I tried the same problem

Comment: check this https://medium.com/@edwardprokopik/how-to-create-a-transparent-safearea-in-flutter-with-colorfulsafearea-e03eceb9ae91

Comment: also doesn't work for me

Comment: Is the white color still visible?