# Flutter - conditionally hide status bar if app is in landscape mode

Tags: dart, flutter

In [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877288/hide-android-status-bar-on-flutter-app), app can hide the status bar with

```
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

But if I surround that with a media query to detect orientation in the main app, it causes the app to error because there is no material ancestor widget.

```
  // app error
  if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  }
```

Is there a way to conditionally hide the status bar in Flutter for the entire app, if the device rotates to landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

`MediaQuery` widget can be accessed only when the ancestor of the widget that you access `MediaQuery` from is a material widget.

A more generic solution without `MediaQuery` would be like:

First

```
import "dart:ui" as ui;
```

then

```
Size s = ui.window.physicalSize/ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
bool landscape = s.width>s.height;

if (landscape) {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
}
```

---

Or

---

Using Orientation builder as root. Inside the build function,

```
 new OrientationBuilder(
   builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation){
             if (orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
               SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
             } else {
               SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values)
             }
             return new Scaffold(...
           }
 );
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: This did not return the status bar on rotate back to portrait. It seems to be called only once. Worse, apparently "SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);" also removes the Android bottom button bar, which also stay removed.

Comment: Yes, call these statements inside a function that listens to orientation changes

Comment: Or consider using [`OrientationBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/OrientationBuilder-class.html) as root. I've changed my answer to implement the same.

Comment: @Hemanth Why does the app not able to take up the entire screen after hiding the system bars?