# Flutter Status Bar transparent

Tags: android, flutter, dart, statusbar, android-statusbar

[image]

How can I make the status and the option bar (on the bottom) transparent?

I tried many thinks but its still black with white text

Here is the code that I already implemented:

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
...
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemStatusBarContrastEnforced: true,
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light));

  
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge,
      overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
...

runApp(...)
```

and in my Material app:

```
return MaterialApp.router(
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            //systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
      ),
      color: Colors.transparent,
...
```

I know that AppBar and status bar is not the same (just wanted to include it anyway).
Thanks so much in advance.

UPDATE:

I tried to remove the Safearea, who apparently conflicted with the status and navigation bar. It resulted in this:

[image]

As now its still not really transparent and also the bottom is messed up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Frank Nike suggests, the SafeArea widget conflicts with the

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light
));
```

Therefore, what solved the problem for me was removing the SafeArea completely and setting:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
      overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently struggled with this too.

My Solution was

```dart
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light
));
```

In my case, safearea was interfering with the changes which made it still show black with white text. I would advice you test on a physical device too.

Comment: Thanks! It helped a little bit (check out Updated version of the question) but its still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming hiding is ok:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Hide Everything:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.leanBack);
```

Hide only bottom:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [
  SystemUiOverlay.bottom
]);
```

Bring them back:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose(); 
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values);  // to re-show bars
  }
```

credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877288/how-to-hide-android-statusbar-in-flutter).