# Unable to hide status bar - Flutter - This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Seeing the following error on setSystemUIOverlayStyle.

Do I have to add some package to pubspec.yaml?

[image: error]

errors:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the StatusBar transparent by adding this in your `main()`:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
```

**The problem** is that you are putting it **inside** your `runApp()`.
Your `main()` should look like this:

```
void main() {
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code I think you write wrong code. for more refer [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877288/how-to-hide-android-statusbar-in-flutter)

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.red,//change color on your need
    ),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this Into your initState() method. this is hide the bottom navigation as well.It is use for Full Screen design.

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

```
 SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
  SystemUiMode.manual,
  overlays: [],
);}
```