# How to make Scaffold body fill the screen from the top of the AppBar to the bottom of the screen in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, scaffold

I have a transparent `AppBar` and I want the `body` of the `Scaffold` to start from the top of the `AppBar` and end at the bottom. My code is as follows:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text('Test Page'),
      ),
      body: Container(color: Colors.teal),
    )
```

The result is:

[image]

And after adding `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` as in the following code:

```
Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text('Test Page'),
      ),
      body: Container(color: Colors.teal),
    )
```

The result is:

[image]

But I want it to start from the top of the `AppBar` as:

[image]

How can this be achieved?! Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to hide date & time as well as upper layer of the screen?

Comment: This link could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877288/how-to-hide-android-statusbar-in-flutter

Comment: You can use  this . Just remove the appbar .Scaffold(
    
 
      body: Container(color: Colors.teal),
    )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `Scaffold` in a `SafeArea` widget:

```
SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            title: const Text('Test Page'),
          ),
          body: Container(color: Colors.teal),
        ),
      )
```

The `SafeArea` is "a widget that insets its child by sufficient padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system."

More information in: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html

Answer (score 4):

Try to wrap `Scaffold` inside `SafeArea`

Code Structure

```
SafeArea                      Add Parent SafeArea widget
|_ Scaffold
  |_ extendBodyBehindAppBar : true
  |_ appBar
```